# Executing an init script in docker-compose before all the services start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which has my services. It starts perfectly fine when I issue the command `docker-compose up --build`.

I want to present a small questionnaire to the user before any of the services start only the first time he uses this `docker-compose`. This is to collect some user details. Is it possible to do this?

PS: I am also experimenting with the `docker-app` plugin. So, solution related to it would also be ok.

Comment: you need to use `wait-for-it.sh` to all other service which should waiting for the service with the `init`

Comment: share your docker-compose or start the service at end using depend_on and wait-for-it as mentioned by @lin